# What is the best practice for implementing smack into an android app?

Tags: java, android, openfire, smack

I'm writing an android game that requires push notification. I've got the aSmack library imported and working, but I don't know how to implement it efficiently to achieve the following:

1.) Each player should be notified when the other player makes a move.
2.) The server should be notified each time either player makes a move, in order to avoid any cheating (such as one player making two moves in a row, etc.)

I've got openfire and aSmack connecting with each other. I need to write a server side program to handle the server-side. Should I put the two users and the server in a group chat? Would it better to have three individual chat sessions?

Comment: Dit you look  in to C2DM for the google android push implementation? http://code.google.com/intl/nl/android/c2dm/index.html

Comment: I did, and I applied, but as of now I can't use it. From the site: _"Android C2DM will ultimately be available to all developers. However, it is currently launched in Labs, and not universally available."_

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/nl/android/c2dm/signup.html you can signup, I had my account within minutes

Comment: hi do u know how to add user in the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to take a look at [XMPP Pubsub](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html).

For C2DM: IIRC it won't suit your use case, as it provides no back channel (only push TO the devices are possible)

Comment: I believe asmack includes Smacks PubSub API to enable this as well.

Comment: Yes, every asmack incarnation I am aware of does have PubSub. But you probably wan't to try an asmack version with is build on smack 3.2.0 because of the better Pubsub support.